# Finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a module, finitely generated,over the  principal ideal domain $D$. 
If $D$ is a field, then $M$ has a basis. But if $D$ is not a field theis is not truth.

Can you give me an example of a module over the integers $\mathbb Z$ finitely generated without a base?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any finitely-generated torsion abelian group will do (and all such groups are actually finite). All elements are annihilated by some nonzero integer, and hence you have no linearly independent sets.

Comment: Notice that torsion is a requirement here. Because finitely generated torsion-free modules over PIDs are free.